# WebView loadRequest method crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code =1, address = 0x10)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My code crashes on this line of the main thread:

->  0x194324c1c <+40>:  ldr    w8, [x0, #0x10]

Here is how I'm loading my WebView: (Note that all this code is in my viewDidLoad method)

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BOR" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:webView];

[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pdfPath]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists!");
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:pdfPath];
    NSURLRequest *fileRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [webView loadRequest:fileRequest];
    });
}
else {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist");
}
```

My code crashes as soon as the line executes:

```
[webView loadRequest:fileRequest]
```

Why is this occurring and how do I go about resolving this issue?